# add blinking network-monitor icon in GNOME / XFCE

Tags: linux, networking, monitoring, xfce, gnome-panel

I'd like to see if i have **incomming or outgoing traffic** via a little blinking network-monitor icon **in my system tray**, as it was usual for years within Windows XP, or Android nowadays.

I want to see if data is being sent or received, **to replace the static icon**. I feel patronized.

What do i need?

Answer (score 0):

I use docky, and there is a neat little docklet that gives you up and down speeds in that fashion.

You can also use something like [netspeed](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/netspeed-traffic-monitor-applet-for-gnome.html) to give you a usage over time graph.

Comment: docky is very nice, but a little too much for me. netspeed is not available in my distribution, unfortunately :( I'll give you an upvote as soon as i have enough rep :)

Comment: which distro are you using?

Comment: fedora 16 with xfce, gnome3 is installed, but one can't really use that.

Comment: [NetMon](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XFCE_simple_Network_Monitor_applet) may be another option.